# Как из словаря добавить значение в список по ключу?

Tags: python, словари

response_json это dict в виде {'user_id':245655}
Мне необходимо добавить значение 'user_id' из этого словаря  в список user_ids.
Таким образом у меня это сделать не получается:

```
user_ids=[]
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

for phone in telephones:
            request = http.request('GET',f'https://api.sonline.su/v1/finduserbyphone/?phone={phone}', headers=headers)
            response = request.data
            response_json = json.loads(response)
            user_ids.append(response_json["user_id"])
print(user_ids)
```

Код ошибки:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 9>()
     11             response = request.data
     12             response_json = json.loads(response)
---> 13             user_ids.append(response_json["user_id"])
     14 print(user_ids)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Ошибки какие-то есть? Попробуйте узнать тип данных которые получаете после запроса

Comment: Ошибка: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
Когда я узнаю тип response_json пишет что это class dict

Comment: @DariaNikolaeva, приложите полный текст ошибки в сам вопрос, нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1443509/edit).

Comment: Проверьте на все ли запросы сервер отдает не пустой словарь

Comment: @Vadik , поправила, прикрепила код ошибки к вопросу

Comment: @ProgerOffline Действительно, на все запросы отдает подобный ответ {'user_id': 53392763} <class 'dict'>, но на один из запросов приходит : [] <class 'list'>

Comment: @ProgerOffline, спасибо большое! Вы очень помогли, сделала проверку на тип, который приходит в ответе, отмела пустой лист и все получилось! Даже не догадалась , что может приходить что-то не то в ответе.